# Trouble checking out LLVM with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, svn, llvm, msysgit, tortoisegit

I'm attempting to check out and build LLVM. In the process I'm trying to get my head around Windows Git installations.

I took the steps listed on this page: 
https://tortoisegit.org/

I first installed TortoiseGit 1.7.10

I then installed Git-1.8.0-preview20121022.exe

I'm not sure what the difference is between this an msysgit. It seems to be the same save the different icon.

After installing (restarting after each) I do a git clone with the tortoise context menu.

As described here: http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#checkout
I set the URL to http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm

I clicked From SVN repository and used the default checkboxes Trunk, Tags, and Branch with respective values trunk, tags, and branches.

I've tried this with and without my putty key.

The Error I get is:

```
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)
```

I'm stumped. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You tried to clone SVN repository with GIT tool. You should clone GIT mirror of LLVM repository with URL: http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git